# keras.estimator.model_to_estimator - Cannot warm-start or load previous checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a tensorflow model by using the keras model_to_estimator function then training with training data. This works fine and I can then go on to successfully predict using test data.

In a separate routine I want to be able to load up the pre-trained estimator with the latest training checkpoint and do more predictions (i.e. without re-training). I've looked at `warm_start_from` but this doesn't seem to be available when loading a keras model. My understanding from https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/checkpoints is that I can just create a new estimator from the same keras model and the first time I predict it will load the checkpoint from the directory I specify.

The following code snippet is my attempt to do this (eventually estimator_model2 will be loaded in a separate routine, this is just to demonstrate).

```
modelConfig = tf.estimator.RunConfig('/myCheckpointpath', keep_checkpoint_max=1)

estimator_model = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=myKerasModel(inputShape, nOutputs), config=modelConfig)            
estimator_model.train(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(_trainData_2d, _trainLabels, batch_size=self.batchSize, shuffle=True, num_epochs=2))

estimator_model2 = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=myKerasModel(inputShape, nOutputs), config=modelConfig)                       
predictions = list(estimator_model2.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(_testData_2d)))
```

From the diagnostics I can see it tries to load the checkpoint when executing the last line. However I get an error that suggests the checkpoint saved during training does not contain all the information required for the new estimator. This is the error:

```
E       NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key conv2d_2/bias not found in checkpoint
E            [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

I can show the keras model if that helps but I don't think that is the issue.

Can anyone give me a solution or suggest a better way to load an estimator with previously trained values just to do predictions?

Comment: I have also raised a feature request for warm_start which would be a way around the above https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20057

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution to the above was to use a hybrid approach where I specify the model with keras notation but then put it in a tensorflow model function which can then be loaded into and estimator. By taking this approach I can save to, and reload from, checkpoints as with any other tensorflow model. I think this gives the best combination of using the intuitive keras notation, while being able to take advantage of the tensorflow estimators and data tools. The following is an overview of my approach describing the setup of the various tensorflow calls:

1. Create an estimator:

   ```
   |--estimator: tf.estimator.Estimator
   |--config: tf.estimator.RunConfig                         #checkpointPath and saving spec for training
           |--model_fn: tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec
               |--myKerasModel                               #specify model. Doesn't have to be keras.
                       |--keras.models.Model
               |--loss: myLossFunction                       #train_and_eval only
               |--optimizer: myOptimizerFunction             #train_and_eval only
               |--training_hooks:tf.train.SummarySaverHook   #train_and_eval only - for saved diagnostics
               |--evaluation_hooks:tf.train.SummarySaverHook #train_and_eval only - for saved diagnostics
               |--predictions: model(data, training=False)   #predict only
   ```
2. Train_and_evaluate:

   ```
   |--tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate
           |--estimator: tf.estimator.Estimator                  #the estimator we created
           |--train_spec: tf.estimator.TrainSpec
                               |--input_fn: tf.data.Dataset      #specify the input function 
                                   |--features, labels           #data to use
                                   |--batch, shuffle, num_epochs #controls for data
           |--eval_spec: tf.estimator.EvalSpec
                               |--input_fn: tf.data.Dataset      #specify the input function
                                   |--features, labels           #data to use
                                   |--batch                      #controls for data
                               |--throttle and start_delay       #specify when to start evaluation
   ```

Note that we could use `tf.estimator.Estimator.train` and `tf.estimator.Estimator.evaluate` but that 
doesn't allow doing evaluations during the training so we use `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` instead.

3. Predict:

   ```
   |--estimator: tf.estimator.Estimator.predict       #the estimator we created
           |--input_fn: tf.data.Dataset               #specify the input function
               |--features                            #data to use
   ```